# Отображение длины строки вместо текста в DataGrid. WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Пытаюсь создать первое приложение WPF с использованием MVVM. Пытаюсь вывести список в DataGrid, он вроде видит список, но выводит вместо текста длину строки. 
Вот мое небольшое окно

```
<Window x:Class="SetAbsElevation.View.MainWindow"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SetAbsElevation.ViewModel"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         Title="{Binding Title}" Height="500" Width="500">


<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainWindowViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="200">
        </ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="80"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <DataGrid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding ListParameterCollection}">

    </DataGrid>

    <Button Name="Button" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10,10,10,10" Content="Выполнить" FontSize="16" Command="{Binding CommandButton}"/>



</Grid>
```

Коллекция, которую передаю в DataGrid

```
vm.ListParameterCollection = new ObservableCollection<string> { "dddddd", "lggds" }; ;
```

На выходе мне показывает длину строк, а я хочу увидеть сами строки `"dddddd", "lggds"`.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно это исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот вариант [без доп классов](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41383837/312041)

```
<DataGrid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" 
         ItemsSource="{Binding ListParameterCollection}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding}" 
                         Foreground="Black" Width="60" Header="Test" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

**ИЛИ**

Определите класс

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Data { get; set; }
}
```

И биндите коллекцию этого класса на грид

```
vm.ListParameterCollection = 
          new ObservableCollection<MyClass> { new MyClass() {Data = "ddddd"}}; ;
```

Comment: В первом варианте редактировать строки, наверное, нельзя будет...

Comment: @АндрейNOP да это я просто скопипастил с ответа на EnSO, убрал ReadOnly флаг

Comment: Да не, убрать ReadOnly флаг не поможет скорее всего, хотя я не проверял, просто интуитивно чувствую, впрочем мы не знаем, нужно ли ТС это вообще

Comment: @АндрейNOP будем надеяться, что у ТСа уже всё хорошо :)